# Generate a ppt File Programmatically

Tags: ios, powerpoint, file-conversion

I am trying to generate a ppt programmatically which basically will have multiple slides with images and text. I tried looking for it but did not find any way to do so, however I find couple of apps that do so [PDF to PowerPoint](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-to-powerpoint/id908959422?mt=8) and [PDF to PowerPoint - Convert PDF to Powerpoint](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-to-powerpoint-convert-pdf-to-powerpoint/id954745624?mt=8).

The first one it seems they are doing the conversion on server but later one is doing it locally

I see that there is no easy or rather I should say in-built way of doing this locally and also I did not find any 3rd party that does so.Can anyone suggest best way to do it? Should I stop for in-app solutions and look for ways to do the conversion on server side?

Answer (score 1):

There is no in-build Apple API for this. Also i haven't heard of any third party to convert in native app itself. If you want to do build one as yourself.

**My approch**

Create a pdf then convert to ppt. You search for how to convert pdf to ppt in ios.

**Other way**

There is a third party application which can do exactly what you want to achieve. But it was using server side coding.

```
pod 'AsposeSlidesCloud'
```

[Github link](https://github.com/aspose-slides/Aspose.Slides-for-Cloud/releases/tag/Aspose.Slides_Cloud_SDK_for_Objective_C_v1.0.0)

Note: The application links you have given where taking longer time to convert the files. I suspect there will be server side support for converting the files.

Comment: Makes sense, but how do I get started is there any format how one should write a data to a ppt file?

Comment: added my way of approch to the same problem

Comment: Thanks, can you provide any leads on how to do that? I did search for the same before asking the question but did not get any positive result. It would be a great help if you can lead me towards a right direction on this.

Comment: which font you need to be used in your ppt file? from where you're getting the images?

Comment: Fonts are not much of a priority, System fonts will do. Images I will be having in my main bundle.

Comment: It looks you may have to deal with machine level coding to achive this. So its better to use the lib i have given, still its faster

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. :) I will try this out and come back to you.